# Произношение слов «мои», «воин»

Tags: орфоэпия

У меня возникло впечатление, что условности орфографии повлияли на произношение таких слов как «мои», «воин».

Может ли быть, что правильное произношение этих слов - «мойи», «войин», т.к. речь однозначно идет об основах ‘моj-‘, ‘воj-‘, звук [j] присутствует во всех остальных словоформах?

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли быть,

Может быть. А может и не быть. Это невозможно объективно установить в рамках русской фонетики.
Попробуйте произнести [мои] и [мойи] в обычном разговорном темпе, без подчеркнутой артикуляции. Вряд ли кто на слух их различит. Причем русский почти наверняка скажет, что никакого "звука Й" там нету, а украинец вероятнее всего будет настаивать, что он там есть.

Попробую объясниться. Похоже, вы хороший вопрос плохо сформулировали, но я постараюсь ответить на "правильный" вопрос.

Орфография здесь ни при чем. **Вопрос стоит о том, как вообще произносятся звуки, соответствующие буквам И и Й в разных позициях и как их передать с помощью разных систем фонетической транскрипции.**

Причем надо понимать, что речь идет о системах, ориентированных на русский язык, ибо понятие одинакового/разного звука справедливо только в рамках одного языка, для другого это неверно.

Так вот, давайте разберемся, какие звуки, соответствующие этой паре букв, существуют в русском языке. Их минимум три.  Это **j** - йот, передаваемый буквой Й в некоторых случаях (в словах типа ***йод, майор*** и т.д. Это **ɪ** - неслоговое И, передаваемое буквой И в словах *бой, сарай, чайка, обойма* и проч, и, наконец, **i** - собственно И.

Так вот. В слове **мои** - в сравнении его со словом мой - исходное **ɪ** (неслоговое И) попало в позицию перед И. И тут есть три подхода. Можно предполагать, что звук **ɪ** частично сохранился в данном сочетании, то есть транскрипция будет **[моɪи]**, можно полагать, что этот звук полностью уподоблен последующим гласным и растворился в нем, что передается транскрипцией **[мои]**, наконец, имея в виду то, что русский язык с исторических времен избегает зияния гласных, можно полагать, что после "растворения" неслогового звука в слоговом, на стыке  ОИ возник вставной (эпентетический) звук **j**, тогда правильной передачей будет **[моjи]**.

Единственно правильного варианта тут нет. Это объясняется тем, что различия, передаваемые этими тремя вариантами, не носят смыслоразличительного характера и на слух носителя русского языка варианты не воспринимаются как разные.

Со словом **воин** примерно та же картина, только несколько осложненная тем, что проблема возникает на стыке корня и суффикса. Это приводит к тому, что услышать йот там как бы проще - в силу наличия однокоренных слов типа военный, где йот возникает на месте зияния гласных, хотя в исходном корне "вой", как уже было сказано, реализуется не йот, а неслоговой звук И. Но в остальном ситуация та же, что и со словом "мои" - все три варианта транскрибирования возможны.

(+)

В качестве некоторого резюме выскажу мысль, что проблема правильности упирается не в то, как это произносят, а в то, как это слышат.

*Написал на скорую руку, без вычитки, проверю позже, извините.*

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, речь не идёт об *исправлении произношения* под условные принципы разделения слов на основу и прочие части. Да, иногда *региональные* произносительные влияния проявляются в попытке транкрипции иностранных слов через "й", например "Тайланд" вместо "Таиланд", "биткойн" вместо "биткоин", "Пинк Флойд" вместо "Пинк Флоид". Но независимо от того, повлияло ли когда-то возникновение письменности на произношение предложенной в вопросе группы слов, для стандартного (не регионального) русского произношения предлагаемая фонетическая запись **неверна**: она противоречит *физиологической артикуляции*, поскольку *попытке*  произношения звука j (й) соответствует смыкание средней части языка с верхним нёбом, чего в приведённых словах с "и" явно нет. В слове "воин" два слога, в слове "войн" (род. п. от "война") - один.

Обобщение относительно "всех остальных словоформ" тоже неверно: обратите внимание на слово "воинственный",  в котором (в рамках стандартного произношения) невозможно заподозрить присутствие звука "й (j)": "и" произносится так же, как и в начале слова ("искра" и т. п.).

Comment: *она противоречит физиологической артикуляции* - Ээээ... В русском языке Йот относится к щелевым звукам. Ни о каком полном смыкании языка с небом речь идти не должна. К тому же в интервокальной позиции произносится не совсем так, как начале слова. Да и вообще смыкание языка с небом - вещь весьма относительная, на слух может не восприниматься, это ж не гортанная смычка, которая как мёд: "или она есть - или её нет".  йот . И самое главное краинском *воїн* произносится совершенно неотличимо от русского варианта, однако по всем учебникам звук йот там таки есть.

Comment: Вообще чистый русский йот можно получить как звонкую пару к мягкому Х. Вы произносите ХЬ (в словах "слухи", "блохи") со смыканием языка? Если нет (а я уверен, что нет), произнените эти слова со звонким Х. Что получится? Неужели не йот, неотличимый от того, что в "воин"?